# node.js-express : How to Fix [object Object] Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

### This is my Code

```
 async login(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const {username, password} = req.body;
      const user = await UserModel.findOne({username});
      if(!user) throw {status: 401, message:'نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه میباشد'}
      const compareResualt = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
      if(!compareResualt) throw {status:401, message:"نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه میباشد"}
      return res.status(200).json({
        status:200,
        success:true,
        message:'شما با موفقیت وارد شدید',
        token:""
      })
    } catch (error) {
      next(error)
    }
  }
```

---

im try to handdle error with try&catch but in out put retrun:[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

you should use new Error() when you throw an error to the error handler
for example :

```
 throw new Error('نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه میباشد');
```